# Using Tabletop.js, trying to fetch data from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, tabletop.js

## Problem

Trying to fetch data from this array, which currently contains two objects. I'm using Tabletop.js to fetch the data from a public Google Spreadsheet, getting an error in the console that says `ReferenceError: object is not defined`

### Console

```
 [Object, Object]/*
    */0: Object
    citation1url: "http://brandonsun.com"
    citation2url: ""
    citation3url: ""
    datesaid: "2/20/2015"
    explanation: ""
    politicianname: "First Name, Last Name"
    rowNumber: 1
    statement: "This is my statement"
    validity: "True, False, Unconfirmed"

    *1: Object
    citation1url: "http://andrewnguyen.ca"
    citation2url: ""
    citation3url: ""
    datesaid: "2/20/2015"
    explanation: ""
    politicianname: "Andrew Nguyen"
    rowNumber: 2
    statement: "I work as a newsroom developer"
    validity: "TRUE"
```

### scripts.js

```
$(function() {
    window.onload = function() { init() };

      var public_spreadsheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1glFIExkcuDvhyu5GPMaOesB2SlJNJrSPdBZQxxzMMc4/pubhtml";

      function init() {
        Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
                         callback: showInfo,
                         simpleSheet: true } )
      }

      function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
        // alert("Successfully processed!")
        console.log(data);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've defined data in that 2nd function showInfo.

I think the best way is to make a variable for your tabletop model, like

```
var tabletop = Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url, callback: function(data, tabletop) { console.log(data) }, simpleSheet: true });
```

Then you can call it:

```
$("#myDiv").html(tabletop.data()[1].Statement);
```